# Adding Admob Google Play Services into Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, admob

I'm trying to migrated from Android SDK to Google Play Services for Admob.  I'm having problems with adding in the java code on the fragment side.

It's an Activity that uses fragments as Tabs to navigate between XML layouts.  In the past I was able to add all the admob information directly in the XML layout.  Google Services requires you to have it linked on the java side.

It keeps on crashing, and I can't figure how to handle the AdView with the fragements.  I was looking at adding it into the Main.java but unsure how TabListener will handle the AdView.

I need some help on this one.

I already done the following items:
1. Add Google Play services library into my project
2. I declared all permission in the manifest

```
  <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"     android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScr    eenSize" />

   <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

I have a Main.java and TabListener to switch between the fragments but can't figure out how to link the Adview xml to the Fragments.

It can't see the views in the fragment, and it doesn't work in the Main.java.

```
 AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
 AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
 adView.loadAd(adRequest)
```

Main.java is my main.

```
 public class Main extends Activity {
 // Declare Tab Variable
 ActionBar.Tab Tab1, Tab2, Tab3;
 Fragment fragmentTab1 = new FragmentTab1();
 Fragment fragmentTab2 = new FragmentTab2();
 Fragment fragmentTab3 = new FragmentTab3();


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

    // Hide Actionbar Icon
    // Set to False, we are not using icons
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

    // Hide Actionbar Title
    // Set to False, used up too much space on phones
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    // Create Actionbar Tabs
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Set Tab Icon and Titles
    // Titles are as follows below
    Tab1 = actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab 1");
    Tab2 = actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab 2");
    Tab3 = actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab 3);

    // Set Tab Listeners
    Tab1.setTabListener(new TabListener(fragmentTab1));
    Tab2.setTabListener(new TabListener(fragmentTab2));
    Tab3.setTabListener(new TabListener(fragmentTab3));

    // Add tabs to actionbar
    actionBar.addTab(Tab1);
    actionBar.addTab(Tab2);
    actionBar.addTab(Tab3);


}
}

TabListener.java for switching between fragments.

public class TabListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {

Fragment fragment;

public TabListener(Fragment fragment) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.fragment = fragment;
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);

}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ft.remove(fragment);
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

My XML fragmentTab1 for example.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:background="@drawable/background1"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent">  

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView 
          xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                    android:id="@+id/adView"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                     ads:adUnitId="@string/admob_string"
                     android:gravity="bottom"
                     ads:adSize="BANNER"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your AdView code needs to go in your Fragment.java class not your Main.java class.  Also, a standard convention would be to name "Main" MainActivity.java rather than Main.java.